# Trying to get jQuery to fire alert when textarea of a certain class focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alert the ID of a textarea when you focus out of the textarea. Either that or if the value changes inside the textarea it doesn't matter too much. I have read that the .live has depreciated and obviously textarea doesn't have a .focusout function. Here is what I have tried so far

```
<textarea id="<?php echo $row->payID; ?>" class="someClass">
```

That is my html I am using

```
$("textarea").on('focusout','.someClass',function () {
alert("Hello");
});
```

And here is my jQuery

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/gR4Qw/

Comment: It works fine, but you might want to try `.blur()` instead.

Comment: exactly!  `onblur()` in JS, but definitely `blur` in `.on`

Comment: That all worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `blur` not `focusout`, like so:

```
$("textarea").on('blur','.someClass',function () {
alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: OP can use whatever it appropriate: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/ >>The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that is what OP asked for.  Just wants to alert when focuses out of the actual textarea, not descendant elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'change' event.

```
<input type="text" id="foo">
$('#foo').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

For on focus lost use:

```
$("#foo").on('blur','',function () {
alert("hi");
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FhnGL/